# Load beans after flyway has migrated the database using flyway-spring-test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, flyway

I have few spring beans (loaded using `@PostContruct`) whose responsibility it is load/recreate the configuration from the config tables at the application bootstrap.

I used `@AutoConfigureAfter(FlywayAutoConfiguration.class)` to make sure that my beans are configured after flyway auto configuration is complete.

The database gets populated fine during normal application launch. However, during the testing using `@FlywayTest` (used at test class level, not test), the database migration happens after the beans are fully constructed.

Is there a way by which I can force flyway to migrate before calling my bean's `@PostConstrcut`

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Comment: Have you come up with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

- Which spring annotations are on your test setup?
- Which Test Setup Configuration do you use in the test? `@Configuration` ...
- Why you need a database reset after correct load of your spring-boot application? May be I can give you a alternative test possibility.

You can also find a very simple spring-boot-example with a minimal setup: [spring-boot-test-examle](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions/blob/master/flyway-test-extensions/flyway-test-samples/flyway-test-spring-samples/spring-boot-sample-flyway/src/test/java/org/flywaydb/sample/test/spring/boot/flywaytest/FlywayTestApplicationTest.java). May be this helps you, but I think not. 
The problem will be that your beans and the `@FlywayTest` annotation depends on flyway bean and so on `FlywayAutoConfiguration`.

May be we can develop together a solution and integrate this in flyway-test-extensions so feel free to open a issue at https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions/issues.

Florian